# how to build super smooth slow motion?

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-processing, video-processing

How do I build a super smooth slow motion in using opencv. It doesn't have to be real time. This is as far as I got. I obtained a frame and the successive frame and calculated the optical flow of all pixels using gunnar farneback algorithm. Then I calculated the back and front coordinates of every pixel and calculated the corresponding interpolated frame pixel to be a linear interpolation of the pixel values in the previous frame at back coordinate and the successive frame at the front coordinates.

I am still unable to get the smooth slow motion that you get in premium software. Any links, algorithms, papers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [block matching](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/blockmatching.html)? basically any method that can provide per-frame-differences. video codecs contain lots of them. advanced stuff IMO.